# When to use addicting vs. addictive?

Tags: adjectives

We're having a debate in the kitchen about this. When would I use `addicting` vs `addictive`?

Comment: isn't this an ESL question?

Comment: No, this is an LSD question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but **addictive** is more common, and is only ever used as an adjective (whereas **addicting** can be either verb or adjective.)

Source: [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/addictive-versus-addicting)